# A simple animation if the app is launched for the first time?

Tags: ios, swift

**In swift,** I have an app that on the first launch shows a "tutorial." I want a simple animation where the first animates in and the second comes in after. I want it to be **very** quick. Although, with my current code, it all appears right when the view/app loads.

**CODE:**

```
let welcomeLabel = UILabel()
let learnToPlayButton = UIButton()
welcomeLabel.alpha = 0
learnToPlayButton.alpha = 0
welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome to ReactFast!"
        welcomeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 35)
        welcomeLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        welcomeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 30, 400, 200)
   learnToPlayButton.setTitle("Click here to learn how to play.", forState: .Normal)
        learnToPlayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        learnToPlayButton.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 35)
        learnToPlayButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        learnToPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: "learnToPlay:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        learnToPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(37, 70, 500, 200)
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasLaunchedOnce") {
            //app has already launched before
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedOnce")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            //first time launch

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
                self.view.addSubview(self.welcomeLabel)
                self.view.addSubview(self.learnToPlayButton)
                self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1.0
                self.learnToPlayButton.alpha = 1.0
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the lack of animation is being caused by the placement of your animation code. viewDidLoad is too early in the view controller's lifecycle for you to be trying to animate anything there.

What you should do instead is leave all your setup code in viewDidLoad, but then add your animation code in the viewDidAppear: method so that the animation starts as soon as the view actually appears on scree.